# OLAP4J: How to connect to a Cube using username and password

Tags: java, olap-cube, olap4j

I am using olap4j libraries and trying to connect to a SSAS Cube.
I understand that the general syntax is,

```
Class.forName("org.olap4j.driver.xmla.XmlaOlap4jDriver");
Connection conn = DriverManager
            .getConnection("jdbc:xmla:Server=http://10.239.0.1/OLAP/");
```

But, if the Cube expects an username and password to connect to it. What is the code syntax that I need to follow to connect?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer to this.

```
Class.forName("org.olap4j.driver.xmla.XmlaOlap4jDriver");
Connection conn = DriverManager
            .getConnection("jdbc:xmla:Server=http://10.239.0.1/OLAP/", username, password);
```